# Restricting flow access of nodes in Corda network

Tags: permissions, corda

My Corda application is working well except for the permissions management. Currently every node can start every flow, however this should not be possible. I tried to restrict the permissions of certain nodes in the `build.gradle` file. Here is one node as an example:

```
 node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=Paris,C=FR"
        p2pPort 10008
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10009")
            adminAddress("localhost:10049")
        }
        rpcUsers = [
    [ 
        user: "user2",
        password: "test",
        permissions: ["StartFlow.FlowInitiatorOne","StartFlow.FlowInitiatorTwo"]
    ]
]
    }
```

I deploy my network using the `deployNodes` command. My flows are written in Java. Regardless of the permissions, `PartyA` is able to start all flows. The log file of `PartyA` shows that all flows are registered, before the permissions are added to the node.

```
[INFO ] 2019-12-13T09:35:25,796Z [main] internal.NodeFlowManager.registerInitiatedFlow - Registered com.template.flows.FlowInitiatorOne to initiate com.template.flows.FlowResponderOne (version 1)
[INFO ] 2019-12-13T09:35:25,797Z [main] internal.NodeFlowManager.registerInitiatedFlow - Registered com.template.flows.FlowInitiatorTwo to initiate com.template.flows.FlowResponderTwo (version 1)
[INFO ] 2019-12-13T09:35:25,798Z [main] internal.NodeFlowManager.registerInitiatedFlow - Registered com.template.flows.FlowInitiatorThree to initiate com.template.flows.FlowResponderThree (version 1)
[INFO ] 2019-12-13T09:35:25,800Z [main] internal.NodeFlowManager.registerInitiatedFlow - Registered com.template.flows.FlowInitiatorFour to initiate com.template.flows.FlowResponderFour (version 1)
[INFO ] 2019-12-13T09:35:25,793Z [main] internal.NodeFlowManager.registerInitiatedFlow - Registered com.template.flows.FlowInitiatorFive to initiate com.template.flows.FlowResponderFive (version 1)
```

Below the flow registrations, the log file shows the user with the right permissions

```
[INFO ] 2019-12-13T09:35:55,434Z [main] security.RPCSecurityManagerImpl.buildImpl - Constructing realm from list of users in config [User(user2, permissions=[StartFlow.FlowInitiatorOne, StartFlow.FlowInitiatorTwo])]
```

If I enter `flow list` in the terminal, `PartyA` will tell me that it can start all five flows. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup is correct and what you see in the log makes sense as well.
 1. When the node starts, it scans the `cordapps` folder and registers all the flows that it sees.
 2. Since you are connecting to the node directly (not through `ssh` or using the `standalone` shell) and your node is in `dev` mode; then Corda connects you to the node as user `shell` with password `shell` and you can run all flows.
 3. To test your RPC user, you would have to write a client that connects to your node using the `test` user; that client will be restricted to calling only the 2 flows that you specified.

Read about different the types of accessing the node: https://docs.corda.net/shell.html

You can see a sample client in R3's cordapp-example (it's in Kotlin):
1. In the controller class, you call the flows using the `proxy`: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/cordapp-example/clients/src/main/kotlin/com/example/server/MainController.k
2. Notice how the Gradle task to run that webserver uses the defined RPC user: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/69ff8d4a668c520b6695be67864f4f96ab7ec809/cordapp-example/clients/build.gradle#L64
3. The Java template comes with a predefined `clients` module as well: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java/tree/release-V4/clients/src/main/java/com/template/webserver

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem now, but I have struggle launching the client with Java. I found this article https://medium.com/corda/corda-rpc-reconnecting-client-eb5d9593e480, but my `build.gradle` file fails to submit the node info to the client.

Comment: This repo has a well documented example with a client calling a flow through RPC: https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/cordapp-example